# how to import function in angular2 using angular-cli?

Tags: function, angular, import, angular-cli

I've previously used the following code

```
import { clone } from '../../utilities/javascript';
```

and in the javaccript.ts

```
export function clone(source: any) {...}
```

In my module i made the call using the following syntax:

```
this.x=clone(y);
```

And all was working.
However, since I am using Angular-cli, the following exception comes up in Chrome:

> error_handler.js:47    EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'clone' of undefined

Is there something in my syntax that is wrong, which surfaced just as I switched to Angular-cli?

I currently copy this function into every module in which i use it, which solves the problem, but that is not something I am comfortable with.

Comment: What does exception tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to import it in the following way:

```
import * as javascriptUtils from '../../utilities/javascript';
```

then call it with:

```
this.x=javascriptUtils.clone(y);
```

taken from https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation